# Iterating through a column, creating new worksheet based on cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Want to iterate through column first checking if name in the excel exists as a worksheet, if not then create a worksheet with that name, but existing code does not work.

```
Sub genWorksheet()

' for loop to iterate through column b
' get name from column b and store name n variable
' checks if a worksheet with the name in the cell exists
' if not, then it will create a new worksheet

Dim myRow As Integer
Dim categoryName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shtName As String
Dim found As Boolean

myRow = 4

Do While Cells(myRow, 1) <> ""
    
    myRow = myRow + 1
    categoryName = Range("B" & myRow) 'Set variable equal to the category name
    
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'For each sheet in the workbook
        
        found = False ' set found = false
        
        If sht.name = categoryName Then ' check if the sheet name equals too  category name
            found = True ' if it does then set found equal to true
            End If
        
        If found = True Then ' break out of the loop since we did find a match
            Exit For
            End If
                    
    Next sht
    
    If found = False Then ' if no match was foundthen add the new sheet
        Sheets.Add.name = categoryName
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Here is the excel data if needed:

[Picture of the excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byFN1.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

Firstly, you increment `MyRow` immediately after testing, not at the end of the iteration. The increment needs to go at the end of your loop.

Secondly, you haven't specified in your code which worksheet column B is on. This is probably fine when you start the loop, but once a worksheet is found to be missing, it creates the worksheet and thereafter starts looking *at that worksheets* column B - which will be empty and cause the loop to stop.

I have a shorter way to test if a worksheet exists - which removes the need for the inner loop. Here is my revised version of your code which I believe will suit your purposes:

```
Sub genWorksheet()
    
    ' for loop to iterate through column b
    ' get name from column b and store name n variable
    ' checks if a worksheet with the name in the cell exists
    ' if not, then it will create a new worksheet
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim categoryName As String
    
    With ActiveSheet ' or specify the name with: Worksheets("sheetname")
    
        myRow = 4
        
        Do While .Cells(myRow, 1) <> ""
            
            categoryName = .Range("B" & myRow) 'Set variable equal to the category name
               
            If Evaluate("ISREF('" & categoryName & "'!A1)") = False Then ' if no match was foundthen add the new sheet
                Sheets.Add.Name = categoryName
            End If
            
            myRow = myRow + 1
            
        Loop
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I note that you're getting the sheet name from column **B**, but you're testing column **A** to ensure you've not reached the end of your list. Is that your intention? If not, change `Do While .Cells(myRow, 1)..` to `Do While .Cells(myRow, 2)..` to perform your test on column **B**